# Getting a map marker by its ID and Index when click on particular marker in google map

Tags: android

I'm using a map in one of my applications. I'd like to know what's a common/efficient way to get the associated Object of a marker when it is clicked.
and also i'd like to know what's a current index of a marker.

Comment: but how? i don't know about HashMap give me some example please.

Comment: search on _google_ `how to use HashMap in Android ?`

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                           
.position(MELBOURNE)                           
.title("Melbourne")                           
.snippet(KEY + "Population: 4,137,400"));

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { 
       String s = marker.getSnippet()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one

```
     {
private Marker myMarker;    

private void setUpMap()
{
    .......
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("My Spot")
                .snippet("This is my spot!")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    ......
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
    {
        //handle click here
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/hashmap/java-hashmap-example/) you can see the HashMap Example.

You create a global HashMap variable like

```
HashMap< Marker, YourClass> hashMap=new HashMap<Marker, YourClass>();
```

Put you marker as a key and your object as a value when you are adding a marker on map like

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                        options.position(new LatLng(Lat, Lng));
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_your_marker));
                        Marker mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
                        mMarker.setTitle("Title");
                        hashMap.put(mMarker,YourClassObject);
```

Then override onMarkerClick method like

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { 
      YourClass obj=(YourClass) hashMap.get(marker);
//now you can use corresponding object
    }
```